# AngularJS - How to set text input on drill-down from another form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular. I have designed a single-page app with a series of screens with input forms, some of which need to "drill down" into another screen and auto-fill the destination input form.

Screen #1: After user fills in the form he gets results in a table. Each row in the table displays an entry with the first cell containing a link the user can click for further details about it, for instance:

```
       <td><a ng-click="drillExtDet(e.extractRequestId)"> {{e.extractRequestId}}</a></td>
```

The controller for this screen has a drillExtDet function as follows, which sets the id into the scope and then activates the detail screen:

```
$scope.drillExtDet = function(extractRequestId) {
    $scope.extrReqId = extractRequestId;
    $location.path('/queryExtDet');
}
```

The new screen is activated, but there are two issues. The form is not getting filled in, and then I also want the form to automatically submit so the details are retrieved.

Screen #2: Has an input form with a field for the extract request id and a Query button:

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Extract Request ID* </p>
            <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control" ng-model="extrReqId" ng-change="resetMessage()" style="width:100px">
            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary"
                ng-click="queryExtDet()" style="width:100px">
                <i class="fa fa-shield">&nbsp;</i>Query
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Below this form is a table which displays all the details. How can I get the input field populated, and how can I then make the form auto-submit?

EDITED to add Solution, thanks to accepted answer below:

The Screen #1 drillExtDet function was modified to add the extractRequestId to the $location.path:

```
$scope.drillExtDet = function(extractRequestId) {
    $scope.extrReqId = extractRequestId;
    $location.path('/queryExtDet/' + extractRequestId);
}
```

I added a second entry for Screen #2 in my route provider table:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/queryExtDet', {
            templateUrl : 'app/queryExtDet.htm',
            controller : 'queryExtDetCtrl'
        })
        .when('/queryExtDet/:extrReqId', {  // with route param to support drill-down
            templateUrl : 'app/queryExtDet.htm',
            controller : 'queryExtDetCtrl'
        })
```

In the Screen #2 controller I added the $routeParams argument:

```
app.controller('queryExtDetCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
```

Then my Screen 2 controller was modified to include code to check $routeParams and invoke the queryExtDet() function which sends the request to the server and populates the new screen (the same thing that my submit function does):

```
$scope.extrReqId = $routeParams.extrReqId;
if ($scope.extrReqId !== undefined) {
    queryExtDet($scope.extrReqId);
}

$scope.submit = function() {
    //console.log("queryExtDetCtrl.submit() invoked with extrReqId="+$scope.extrReqId);
    if (!$scope.extrReqId) {
        $scope.message = "'Extract Request ID' is required!";
    } else {
        queryExtDet($scope.extrReqId);
    }
}

function queryExtDet(extractRequestId) {
    $scope.extrReqId = extractRequestId;
    if (!$scope.extrReqId) {
        $scope.message = "'Extract Request ID' is required!";
    } else {
        // $http.get etc.
    }
}
```

On the input form side, the input field had to be changed from type="number" to type="text", otherwise it would not work:

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Extract Request ID* </p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="extrReqId" placeholder="Extract Request Id" ng-change="resetMessage()" style="width:100px" required>
            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary"
                ng-click="submit()" style="width:100px">
                <i class="fa fa-shield">&nbsp;</i>Query
            </button>
            <a href="/TCSCWebServices/rest/export/extDet;fmt=csv;extrReqId={{extrReqId}}"><i class="fa fa fa-retweet"></i> Export</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: For SPA, you must be using some routing mechanism. If you are using `ngRoute`, You can pass `extrReqId` as param to Screen #2 and retrieve the same using `$routeParams`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing the `extrReqId` as params, you can access the previous data using API to get those details and by using `ng-change` and form validation, you can auto submit the data.

Comment: Thanks deepica - Using $routeParam I'm able to now populate the input field. But I have not been successful at auto-submitting the form. I tried ng-change on the input field but it doesn't seem to cause anything to be called as a result of input field changing from the route param (it only gets called when the user is typing in the input field). You mentioned using ng-change together with form validation, can you elaborate on how form validation fits in?

Comment: Actually I found that my screen 2 controller was being invoked, I only had to invoke the submit function programatically. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

i expected the forms are editable and extra fields are present  in new screen , if they aren't then  no need to use ng-change , after getting details from api u can redirect to submit function where u can check all the details are present or not .

```js
$scope.submit=function(){
      if ($scope.userForm.$invalid) {
            alert($scope.userForm.$invalid);
             }else{}}
```

```html
<form name="userForm" novalidate>
       <table><thead> <tr><th>Name</th> <th>Country</th></tr> </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr data-ng-repeat="n in names | orderBy: 'Country'">
                <td> <input type="text" ng-model="n.name" name="uName" required="">
                    <div ng-show="userForm.$submitted && userForm.uName.$error.required">
                </td>
                <td>{{n.country}}</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </form>
```